# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

When starting mysql in XAMPP control panel I get the following error

```
14:35:23  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:35:23  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:35:23  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:35:23  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:35:23  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:35:23  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:35:23  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I have been having this problem with mysql not starting so I've re-installed XAMPP. MYsql then worked but today when starting again I got the above error. I've searched around google to find a solution, I've also deleted this file ibdata1 in the following directory C:\xampp2\mysql\data but Mysql didn't start probably. I had a look in the log files and I am getting the following error

```
2014-02-20 14:35:16 6528 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

Also, this all started after I configured Mysql with grails and hibernate, so I was thinking could the be the issue why I can't start MySQL in Xampp?

Comment: Was it running previously - do you need to preserve any data?

Comment: I was having the same errors previously I then re-installed XAMPP and it did work for a while, I then tried to start mysql today but it's shutting down. And no as I haven't got any important data to save.

Answer (score 1):

You can spend ages trying to find out what has gone wrong - installing over the top can create as many issues as it solves.

I suggest you go for a clean install as you have no data to worry about.

1. Uninstall XAMPP
2. Delete / move directory C:\xampp2\
3. Reboot
4. Instal XAMPP

Test

Answer (score 0):

Open the task manager and stop `mysql`, then just start `mysql` in xampp and you're done.